# Input text doesn't get enabled on mouseclick

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, input

When the user clicks on the center, or on the right side of the text areas of the form (the login form on the right), nothing will happen. It will work only if the user clicks on the left of these areas. This is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/dxzfbfpf/).

This is the form:

```
<form id="login" name="login">
    Username<input type="text" name="userid" size="25"/>
    Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</form>
```

How to make it so that it will get enabled when the user clicks on any side of the text area?

Comment: Can't replicate on Chrome 44 (Mac OS X).

Comment: I am on Chrome 45.0.2454.85 m (win7) @AaronCritchley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last thing in your stylesheet it this:

```
input {
    width: 10% !important;
}
```

Get rid of the rule all together and it will work. It is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Change :

```
input {
    width: 10% !important;
}
```

to :

```
input {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dxzfbfpf/1/

Answer (score 1):

The last item in your CSS is

```
input {
    width: 10% !important;
}
```

Remove it or override with:

```
.ui-input-text input {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Correct, +1, but the other answer was faster by a minute.

Comment: They are both wrong, you don't need the rule at all! :)

Comment: @JohnFable, that's why I said "Remove it or override with". I assumed OP needs the rule elsewhere in the app...